# how to open file from ssh server with client program

Tags: ssh

If I have a file (test.cpp) on my server that i have access to via ssh, is it possible to open that file using a program on my machine such as visual studio code without having to create a copy of the file?

Answer (score 1):

No from ssh, but you can download/upload file using ssh. You will need additional software for network attached filesystem '[SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [SAMBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) etc.' to make the file accessible for the local system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible if you use something like sshfs to mount the remote filesystem on your local system - which uses ssh as a transport to create a virtual drive/path a bit like NFS or Windows Filesharing but over ssh.